# Trimming the last N changes in MediaWiki in order to "rebase" history from a Git-powered backup?

Tags: mediawiki, backups, git

Recently the wiki I administer in some sense has "crashed" due to a database that seems to be completely lost. Just the database, not the MediaWiki installation, extensions or media. Unfortunately, I didn't make any backups relying on the hosting service capabilities, and the large wiki was full on unique content available worldwide now not being accessible after about ten years of stable work. However, there is still a private mirror of the wiki made about a year or two ago that was used as an experimental playground from time to time. Thus both wikis have diverged history. One more thing that can play the crucial role: I have a Git clone of the wiki created with [git-remote-mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git-remote-mediawiki) a month ago.

Actually I would really like to restore the database, and I have some scenario that probably might help restore at least a partial instance. Here is how I think it could work:

- Clone the private experimental database so let the only survived database be untouched.
- In the cloned database, if possible, trim the N last changes to drop all diverged changes (comparing to the lost live database). Is such trimming possible in MediaWiki? (Maybe some of the maintenance scripts?) How big should N be? Actually have no idea yet, probably a sort of "binary search" just reviewing both wikis. Maybe it should be even up to the very first revision if necessary.
- Clone the git-mediawiki backup to keep the original safe, and change the origin in `.git/config` so let it point to the private mirror wiki.
- Push the changes from the git repo to the origin in hope it would restore most pages. As far as I remember, the remote helper does not sync templates, talk pages, user pages and so on. Unfortunately, they seem to be completely unrestorable. Most templates might be restored by memory more or less.

Would it be possible to "trim" the last N changes in MediaWiki to drop the changes in the private mirror in order to restore the pages from the git backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind administrators being able to access those changes, the easiest is to revision-delete them:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:RevisionDelete
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=revisiondelete

If you are looking for a simple solution, you could try dropping entries from the `revision` table in the database (probably makes more sense to use a cutoff timestamp than last N entries) and fixing the `page` table so that `page_latest` points to the last remaining revision for that page. No guarantee this won't break your wiki though.

Comment: I'd like to use the second way, but I'm afraid of making a sort of surgery over the wiki not knowing the exact db tables model and leaving some junk data behind. However, thank you for the tip.

Comment: It will definitively leave junk data behind, but nothing critical, I think. If you want to do it cleanly, you should use revision deletion.

Comment: hm, but doesn't it just hide revisions rather than making a physical cut off revisions for entire wiki?

Comment: It does. Is that difference relevant? MediaWiki has no concept of permanent deletion, making sure everything is undoable is a key concept of the wiki model. Extensions have been created for that purpose (e.g. [DeletePagesForGood](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeletePagesForGood)), but I don't know of any that works per-revision instead of per-page.

Comment: Yes, I guess the difference matter, because I would consider there were no any "new" revisions that diverged since the moment of diverging the public and the private wikis, so that I could just "add"/"push" the public wiki revisions from the git repo backup to the now-clean private wiki. If it just hides, then I think that copying a private wiki database to the public wiki might pull a lot of experimental/dirty/etc stuff I wouldn't like to publish even if they would be visible from history only. That's why I see physical deletion a more appropriate way yet.

Comment: Deleted revisions are not visible in the history or anywhere else unless you have administrator permissions. Anyway if you really want to physically delete, you can run [deleteRevision.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteRevision.php) and then [deleteArchivedRevisions.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php).

Comment: It sounds greats, thank you! The reason of why I am afraid of just hiding the revisions is that I might have issues during `git push` (I have never performed such an operation) as this is the crucial tool for me now.

Comment: Hello! It seems like you also helped me at the MediaWiki Project Support Desk [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:U2hlwsp3k3fmowo6&topic_showPostId=u2mmk4qhmozxrxp1#flow-post-u2mmk4qhmozxrxp1). If you don't mind, could you please also put your answer to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110947/is-it-possible-to-find-broken-link-anchors-in-mediawiki ? Thanks!