# Is it possible to find broken link anchors in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Probably a simple question answered million times, but I can't find an answer. MediaWiki can track missing pages and report those with `Special:WantedPages`. I'm not sure if it's possible, but can MediaWiki report broken anchors? Say, I have the `Foo` page that refers the `Bar` page like this: `[[Bar#Name]]`. Let's assume the `Bar` page lacks this section therefore the *Name* section does not exist there, but `Special:WantedPages` won't report this link as broken because the `Bar` page exists. Is there any way to find all broken anchors? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not very critical, but unfortunately it seems that MediaWiki does not support such a feature out of box, although it was requested multiple times. :( See more at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T18561. Thanks to Ciencia Al Poder from the [MediaWiki Project Support Desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:U2hlwsp3k3fmowo6).

(Edit 1)

Another thanks go to Tgr that suggested to use [BrokenAnchorBot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots/Requests_for_approval/BrokenAnchorBot). This solution requires Pywikibot and seems to really answer the question. Also, Tgr seems to have an [account](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/697/tgr) at the site, and if he puts his answer here too, I'd be happy to mark his answer as the best one since the bot seems to fix my issue without having built-in support.